# How to use requests library in Python for multiple parameters?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm working on a program in Python that takes a vehicle registration and returns its MOT history by using MOT Trade API. So far, I've got the program working for one vehicle. I would like the program to look-up multiple vehicles by importing an excel file that contains a list of vehicle registrations. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'vehicles.xlsx')  # Reading the excel file with the vehicle database
reg = df['registration']

headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': apiKey,
    }

    params = (
        ('registration', reg),
    )
    response = requests.get('https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests',
                            headers=headers, params=params)

def check_days_left():
    r = response.json()  # This returns a list of dicts of the full MOT History data
    carDetails = r[0]  # Access the first dictionary of the list which is MOT tests
    motTests = carDetails['motTests']  # This returns a list of dicts of the MOT tests
    latestTest = motTests[0]  # Access the first dictionary to get the details of the latest test
    expDate = latestTest['expiryDate']  # This returns the expiry date key of the latest test dictionary
    uk_date = datetime.strptime(expDate, '%Y.%m.%d')  # Convert expDate to datetime format
    difference = uk_date - datetime.now()  # Gets the timedelta between now and expiry date
    days_left = difference.days  # Extract the number of days from the above as an int
    print(days_left)

check_days_left()
```

At the moment, this returns the MOT details for the last vehicle in the excel file, ignoring the rest. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use a for loop to loop through all the registration numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the registration number and request to the api to get result of each registration number.

A working solution might look like following code -

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib
import time
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'vehicles.xlsx')  # Reading the excel file with the vehicle database
registrations = df['registration'].tolist()

r = []

# loop through all the registration number in registrations array.
for reg in registrations:
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': apiKey,
    }
    params = {
        'registration': reg,
    }
    # Add the response from the api in the array `r`
    r.append(requests.get('https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests', headers=headers, params=params).json())


def check_days_left():
    r = response.json()  # This returns a list of dicts of the full MOT History data
    carDetails = r[0]  # Access the first dictionary of the list which is MOT tests
    motTests = carDetails['motTests']  # This returns a list of dicts of the MOT tests
    latestTest = motTests[0]  # Access the first dictionary to get the details of the latest test
    expDate = latestTest['expiryDate']  # This returns the expiry date key of the latest test dictionary
    uk_date = datetime.strptime(expDate, '%Y.%m.%d')  # Convert expDate to datetime format
    difference = uk_date - datetime.now()  # Gets the timedelta between now and expiry date
    days_left = difference.days  # Extract the number of days from the above as an int
    print(days_left)

check_days_left()
```